# Calling functions without parameters even if they have them defined?

Tags: c++, arduino, arguments

I have recently used the [HX711](https://github.com/bogde/HX711) library for the Arduino Uno. However, I am struggling to understand how this library works for a specific command. This library functions allow me to read load and time data from a load cell.

When I run my Arduino code, I call the `get_units` function. This function is defined as follows in the library:

```
float HX711::get_units(byte times) {
    return get_value(times) / SCALE;
}
```

This command depends on `get_value` and `read_average` as follows:

```
long HX711::read_average(byte times) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (byte i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        sum += read();
        yield();
    }
    return sum / times;
}

double HX711::get_value(byte times) {
    return read_average(times) - OFFSET;
}
```

I don't see a place within the library where `byte` or `times` are explicitly defined. However, when I call the `get_units()` command in my code, I don't pass any parameters inside.

What are the purpose of `byte` or `times` and how do they affect how my data is collected? What happens by default when I don't feed either of these parameters into the get_units() function?

Comment: Find all occurrences of get_units in all header files. Do you see something unusual?

Comment: No? What do you mean by unusual?

Comment: Something that you didn't expect. Something like `float get_units(byte times = 1);` perhaps?

Comment: Near the beginning of the method, I call HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK), where Dout and clk refer to the clock and data out pins from the load cell. When I call get units later, I call it as scale.get_unit(). I also did try calling get_units(1), but that doesn't seem to make a difference. In that case, which parameter would be defined as 1? Byte or times?

Comment: There's one parameter named times. Its type is byte.

Answer (score 0):

`get units` is [defined in HX711.h](https://github.com/bogde/HX711/blob/master/HX711.h) with a [default argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments). This is why it may be called with or without an argument.

Comment: Yes, I understand that there is some default value used when I don't pass one in. However, I don't understand what it is for bytes or time based upon the hx711 library. As you said before, in the library it say get_units(byte times = 1), bu I don't understand how much time over which it is averaged, so to speak, or what the byte does.